# prepareForSegue in SWRevealViewController with Swift

Tags: swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to write `prepareForSegue` in `SWRevealViewController` with Swift.
Here is my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)
{
    if(segue!.identifier == "segueName")
    {
        var someText = "Text"
        var rvc:newViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as newViewController
        rvc.topText = someText
    }
}
```

In `newViewController` I have `topText` as `NSString`

Of course I got nil text because I should make `SWRevealViewControllerSegue` but I don't know how it should look in Swift

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to use prepareForSegue for SWRevealViewController in Swift? Because this code segue with nothing.

Comment: When you set a breakpoint at the `var someText = "Text"` line, is that breakpoint reached?

Comment: Sure. This code works but do not "send" the text in "newViewController"

Comment: For clarity's sake, always name classes starting with Uppercase, instances starting with lowercase. If `newViewController` is a class it should be `NewViewController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.

First of all need to configure SWRevealControllerSegue. In swift it should looks like:

```
    if(segue.isKindOfClass(SWRevealViewControllerSegue))
    {
        var rvcs: SWRevealViewControllerSegue = segue as SWRevealViewControllerSegue
        var rvc:SWRevealViewController = self.revealViewController()

        rvcs.performBlock = {(rvc_segue, svc, dvc) in
            var nc:UINavigationController = dvc as UINavigationController
            rvc.pushFrontViewController(nc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Second. XCode beta works bad right now with `IBOutlet` and `segue` like this. With variable everything is ok.

Comment: I know is a long time ago and some stuffs have changed like using `SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController`  instead of `SWRevealViewControllerSegue` but can u tell me why am I having an error in 4'th line saying `SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController` dose not have a member named `performBlock`

Answer (score 2):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.isKindOfClass(SWRevealViewControllerSegue))
    {
        var rvcs: SWRevealViewControllerSegue = segue as SWRevealViewControllerSegue
        var rvc:SWRevealViewController = self.revealViewController()

        rvcs.performBlock = {(rvc_segue, svc, dvc) in
            var nc:UINavigationController = self.revealViewController().frontViewController as UINavigationController
            nc.setViewControllers([dvc], animated: true)
            self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPositionLeft, animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems like a "code only" answer. Could you summarize the needed changes in a few sentences?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work with the latest version. The release notes state:

> Took a cleaner approach to storyboard support. SWRevealViewControllerSegue is now deprecated and you should use SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController and SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController instead.

There aren't any swift examples anywhere I can find that explain this though.

The performBlock method no longer exists.

Appreciate any help. It seems impossible to do swift without first learning objective c at the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

What was `newViewController`? This should work:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)
{
    if(segue.identifier == "segueName")
    {
        let someText = "Text"
        let rvc = segue.destinationViewController as SWRevealViewController
        rvc.topText = someText
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Because topText - it is my variable: in newViewController I have @IBOutlet var topText: NSString